# Copying Swift message thats in one cell into multiple rows

Tags: string, vba, csv

I have a spreadsheet with a swift message saved in one cell in csv. I've no way of delimiting this. The only way I can display the message correctly in excel is by copying the string from the formula box and pasting into another cell. Then the message displays properly into individual rows per line of sift message. Unfortunately there are 300+ messages so want to create some VBA code. Any ideas?

Comment: The file is .csv, right? Is there any reason why `Data > From Text > *select your .csv file* > delimited` can't be used? Giving us a sample row of data, as well as clarifying what you mean with "copying the string from the formula box and pasting into another cell" would help us help you. Do you need to match and extract a *part* of the string? Right now it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah csv.Already tried delimiting th efile but cant find where i can split each row.

Comment: Heres a sample of whats in one cell:   {1:TESTESMXXXXX0951234567}{2:O5TEST1234541843N}{4:
:16R:GENL
:20C::SEME//IBC40000013456
:23G:INST
:98C::PREP//201765432326
:16R:LINK
-}